# Порционное чтение и запись в FileStream

Tags: c#, filestream

Для создания утилиты бэкапа, требуется работа перемещения файлов путем FileStream (read,write). Из за большого размера файлов, нужно читать с потока и записывать в поток FileStream по частям, вот кусок кода:

```
    //допустим длина fsstream и array 98875 
    // для порционной работы с потоком мы сделали 
    int filePart=fsstream.Lenght/100;
    while (fstream.Read(array, 0, filePart) > 0)
    {
        fstreamWrite.Write(array, 0, filePart);//пишем данные                         
        Thread.Sleep(100);
    }
```

Проблема в том, что так как деление

```
int filePart=fsstream.Lenght/100;
```

округляет число, файл в destinationFolder-созданный, не попадает несколько байтов, естесственно он как битый(Что делать?

Comment: Из описания ничего не понять. Что за порционная работа? Почему не "просто скопировать файл" с помощью File.Copy или Stream.CopyTo?

Comment: Потому, что требования к производительности, чтобы канал (локальная сеть ) не засорять и нагрузки на ЦП чтобы не было.(файлы есть и под 800 GB)!!File.Copy() естественно не подойдет)

Comment: Порционная, значит - кусочек нужного файлика прочитал(кол-во байт) , этот кусочек  положил в новый-создаваемый файл , и так пока файл весь не прочитан, то бишь читать и писать, но только не сразу весь, а по кускам!

Comment: "бишь читать и писать" - почему вы думаете, что File.Copy (и тем более Stream.CopyTo) читает полный файл и только потом пишет? В реализации есть буфер (дефолтный вроде 85кб), который и используется как "прочитали в буфер - пишем - снова читаем  в буфер"

Answer (score 2):

Нужно сохранять количество прочитанных байтов, которое возвращает `FileStream.Read` и использовать его при вызове `FileStream.Write`:

```
int count = 0;
byte[] buffer = new byte[filePartSize];

do {
    count = sourceStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
    destStream.Write(buffer, 0, count);
} while (count > 0);
```

Comment: не работает, файлы dest -битые и по размеру отличаются от оригиналов в несколько байт, такое чувство, что нужно дописывать в цикле остаток (от длины файла)

Comment: @user344622, этот код должен работать правильно. Вы его без изменений перенесли?